# Checkbox buttons not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I got to style my check boxes using a CSS technique from one site. The problem is that the styled checkbox is not working in my site. However its working on the downloaded HTML demo.

CSS

```
<style>
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1000;
    left:-1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
    margin:-1px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 28px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -28px;
}
label.css-label {
    background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cb.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
</style>
```

Function

```
<?php
function show_bank_terms() {
    $args = array("posts_per_page"   => 10, "post_type" => "fi_bank_search_terms", "order" => "DESC");
    $posts_array = get_posts($args);
    echo "<div class='list-grid'>";
    foreach($posts_array as $post){
        //$search_condition = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_fi_search_condition");
        $search_meta = fi_get_meta($post->ID, "_fi_search_condition");
        //var_dump($search_meta);
        $search_condition = "";
        if(count($search_meta) > 0)
            $search_condition = $search_meta[0]['meta_id'];
        ?>
        <div class="search_options">
            <input name="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" class="css-checkbox" value="<?php echo $search_condition ?>" />
            <label for="checkboxG1" class="css-label" style="padding-left: 40px;"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></label>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Now here from the CSS if I remove `position: absolute;` from the `input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox` then I can see the actual check boxes beside the styled one. They are perfectly working (checking on click) and also reflecting the check on the styled check boxes. But when I click on the styled checkboxes directly it does not work. Nothing happens. I am stuck since yesterday now. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your issue is that the label's for="" isn't equal to the checkbox's id="". You should double check that.

The trick here is that the label is linked to the checkbox, thus allowing us to check it by clicking on the label (the for/id relation).